# passing Multiple conditions to LINQ FirstOrDefault Method

Tags: c#, linq, geolocation

I have a list of `gelolocations`. I want to perform 2 conditions on the list and select the ones which satisfy those conditions. I cannot figure out how to do that.

```
public class GeolocationInfo
{
    public string Postcode { get; set; }

    public decimal Latitude { get; set; }

    public decimal Longitude { get; set; }
}

var geolocationList = new List<GeolocationInfo>(); // Let's assume i have data in this list
```

I want to perform multiple conditions on this list `geolocationList`.

I want to use `FirstOrDefault` on this list on the conditions that `PostCode` property matching with the one supplied and Longitude, lattitude are not null.

```
    geolocationList .FirstOrDefault(g => g.PostCode  == "AB1C DE2"); 
// I want to add multiple conditions like  g.Longitude != null && g.Lattitude != null in the same expression
```

I want to build this `conditions` outside and pass it as a parameter to `FirstOrDefault`.  e.g like building a `Func<input, output>` and passing this into.

Comment: Have you tried putting conditions in comment inside FirstOrDefault?

Comment: I tried and it works but my objective is to not put all conditions inside the `FirstOrDefault`. I gave simple example of `equals` comparision. i have very complex conditions. They are definitely not readable. I want to build an `expression` with those conditions and pass them into `FirstOrDefault`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your response guys. It helped me think in the right way.

I did like this.

```
Func<GeolocationInfo, bool> expression = g => g.PostCode == "ABC" &&
                                              g.Longitude != null &&
                                              g.Lattitude != null;
geoLocation.FirstOrDefault(expression);
```

It worked and code is much better.

Comment: Please mark an answer for the question if the issue is fixed.

Answer (score 3):

You have given your own answer:

```
geoLocation.FirstOrDefault(g => g.Longitude != null && g.Latitude != null);
```

Answer (score 2):

FirstOrDefault can take a complex lambda, for instance:

`geolocationList.FirstOrDefault(g => g.PostCode == "ABC" && g.Latitude > 10 && g.Longitude < 50);`

Comment: You can even get sneakier:
`geolocationList.FirstOrDefault(g => {
  if (g.PostCode.contains("A")) {
    return true; // always accept post codes containing "A"
  }
  return g.Latitude > 10;
})`

Comment: Is there any way i can build this expression outside using `Func<>` and pass it as parameter to `FirstOrDefault`

Comment: If you don't want to use anonymous function, you can try `geolocationList.FirstOrDefault(g => IsParameterOk(g));` and then `bool IsParameterOk(GeolocationInfo g){  /* logic here */ }`

Comment: Sure, you can define your own function `public bool FirstOrDefaultFilter(GeolocationInfo geolocationInfo)` and then just use it: `geolocationList.FirstOrDefault(FirstOrDefaultFilter)`

Comment: @KamilT in this case we don't need lambda `g => IsParameterOk(g)`, the signature of `IsParameterOk` the same as `Func<GeolocationInfo, bool>` which needs for lambda.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static TSource FirstOrDefault<TSource>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, bool> predicate
)
```

> predicate Type: System.Func A function to test each
>   element for a condition.

So you can use any Func that get `TSource` and return `bool`

```
//return all
Func<GeolocationInfo, bool> predicate = geo => true;

//return only geo.Postcode == "1" and geo.Latitude == decimal.One
Func<GeolocationInfo, bool> withTwoConditions = geo => geo.Postcode == "1" && geo.Latitude == decimal.One;

var geos = new List<GeolocationInfo>
{
    new GeolocationInfo(),
    new GeolocationInfo {Postcode = "1", Latitude = decimal.One},
    new GeolocationInfo {Postcode = "2", Latitude = decimal.Zero}
};

//using
var a = geos.FirstOrDefault(predicate);
var b = geos.FirstOrDefault(withTwoConditions);
```